# Mesh Body not showing up in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, makehuman

Hy guys though i am not new to blender but i am posting question for first time ever.

My problem is kinda confusing, I imported a rigged model from MakeHuman using mh2 plugin and then sculpted model to my need.

Alas, when I rendered it, the body is not showing up in render. I checked restrict render, nothings there. I did change material nothings happening, tried CPU and GPU both and back and forth in Internal and Cycles, but nothing changes.

Anyone who would be willing to look into my problem I would be grateful.
Is it bug?

Please do help me because I need image by tonight. Thanks a ton!!

[image]

Comment: check the renderbility toggle for that object in Outliner.

Comment: Hard to tell from image alone. Can you upload your blend file? It's possibly a normal issue

Comment: Without the file is impossible to tell what is going on.